# Find star in an image at give coordinates

Tags: numpy, opencv, image-processing, scipy, python-imaging-library

I have an star image like this

[image]

and a list of the center of the detected stars which looks like this

```
Name;RA(deg);Dec(deg);PixelX;PixelY;RPmag;Gmag;BPmag;Parallax;Flags
;313.311502;44.387289;2516;1458;4.850;4.728;4.681;5.8088;000800f0
;313.327406;45.181692;236;2256;4.517;5.190;5.715;3.6700;000800f0
;314.580976;44.472083;3131;4138;4.660;5.304;5.779;14.4950;00800f00
;314.471585;44.788107;2143;4206;4.358;5.673;7.615;1.9323;000800f0
; ...
```

I want to detect the contour/size of the star at the x,y coordinates of each entry and then write a white dot in the size of the star to a new image.

Has anyone an idea how to use the contour detection of opencv/cv2 on given coordinates?

Comment: How were the stars detected? That process should likely give you all the information you need.

Comment: Thank you for your email. The stars are detected in another software. So I have unfortunately, no chance to get to this process.

Comment: try this: threshold very low, find connected components with stats (!), then look up the *label* at the position (indexing into the labeled image) you already have from the CSV file, then look up the statistics (centroid/width/height/area) for the label in the stats array.

Comment: What are the other columns please? E.g. RPmag? Gmag?

Comment: Start from each center and add + something in one directions until it goes black. Write a circle with that radius in the new picture

Comment: @Mark Setchell RPmag, Gmag, BPmag is the brightnes of the star and Parallax it is parallax measured by Gaia spacecraft. RA(deg) and Dec(deg) is the stars position in the night sky and PixelX and PixelY its center position in the image.

Comment: At the moment I try to code with the ConnectedComponentsWithStats